# Need to close Debugger and restart before saved data can be read

Tags: c#, database, linq

I can open a daily list of school-reservations through a search with a monthcalendar.
The form below shows me the result as a list of schools in the center-grid.

[Form with a list of schools that made a reservation http://www.iwva.be/images/bezoekers/Schools.jpg](http://www.iwva.be/images/bezoekers/Schools.jpg)

This is the code I use to load the data to put into the grid (this is before noon)

```
var vReservationAM = (from oReservation in clsApplication._oDBConnection.tblReservations
                              where oReservation.StartTime >= mcCalendar.SelectionRange.Start.Date
                              && oReservation.StartTime < mcCalendar.SelectionRange.Start.Date.AddHours(12)
                              orderby oReservation.StartTime ascending
                              select oReservation);
```

For every school, I can see what kind of activities they asked for by clicking on the magnifying glass at the beginnning of the row. I then get the list of activities the school has asked for (see form below).

[Form with a list of activities per school http://www.iwva.be/images/bezoekers/Activities.jpg](http://www.iwva.be/images/bezoekers/Activities.jpg)

When I open an acitivity I can change the data and it will be changed in the activity-list as well. So all works fine...except for one strange thing.
When I add a new activity (see form below) it's not getting showed in the activity-list (see form above).

[Form to add an activity http://www.iwva.be/images/bezoekers/AddActivity.jpg](http://www.iwva.be/images/bezoekers/AddActivity.jpg)

Even when I make a new search with the monthcalendar I can only see the activities that were already saved a previous time.

But when I look at the database I can see that the new activity has been saved.

**I have to close my debugger and open it again before the data is being loaded and showed in the grid.**

What can be the cause of this?

Comment: None of your image links are working.

Comment: Without seeing any code (which would be very useful) my best guess is that you're not re-binding the data or in some way updating your UI after making your changes.

Comment: After you add your row, do you query again the database to refresh the information?

Comment: Is that necessary? I run the query again everytime I start a search-action by date (monthcalendar). I added the query I use. But that doesn't work.

Comment: Copy your "This was the cause" into an answer and mark your question as answered.

Answer (score 1):

Found it:

For filling up the grid with activities I ran this loop:

```
foreach (var oReservationDetail in _oReservationObject.ReservationData.tblReservationDetails)
```

I though the relational link in the database would always retrieve the latest data. Appearantely it does not. Once the link has been established it uses the same data.

I replaced it with this:

```
var vActivities = (from oReservationDetails in clsApplication._oDBConnection.tblReservationDetails
                           where oReservationDetails.ReservationID == _oReservationObject.ReservationData.ID
                           orderby oReservationDetails.StartTime ascending
                           select oReservationDetails);

foreach (var oReservationDetail in vActivities)
{
    fill the grid
}
```